# UWP - Filtering ListView with grouping

Tags: listview, windows-10, uwp, collectionviewsource

I have a `ListView` with grouping. I want to display items in this `ListView` according to text entered into `TextBox`. There are many tutorials about filtering a `ListView` and `CollectionViewSource`, but they are for `WPF` not `UWP`. What I'm doing:

My `ListView`:

```
    <ListView x:Name="ContactsListView"
              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ContactsTemplate}"
              ItemsSource="{x:Bind ContactsViewSource.View}"
              SelectionMode="Single"
              ShowsScrollingPlaceholders="True" >

              <ListView.GroupStyle>
                 <GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                       <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:GroupingItem">
                          <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Key}"
                                     Foreground="Blue"
                                     Style="{ThemeResource TitleTextBlockStyle}"/>
                       </DataTemplate>
                    </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                 </GroupStyle>
              </ListView.GroupStyle>
    </ListView>
```

My `CollectionViewSource` is defined in `Page.Resources`:

```
 <CollectionViewSource x:Name="ContactsViewSource"
                       x:Key="src"
                       IsSourceGrouped="True" />
```

I have created a `textChanged` event handler for `TextBox`:

```
private void SearchBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e) {
    ....
    //here I filter ListView items and add them to CollectionViewSource
    ContactsViewSource.Source = filteredValues;
}
```

But no change. ListView is not refreshed. I don't know what to do. I wasn't able to find any solution to this problem for `UWP`.

When assigning data in `MainPage` `constructor` it is displaying data. When I don't assign data in `constructor` but in `SearchBox_TextChanged` there are no data displayed in `ListView`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do note that `x:Bind` default behaviour is `OneTime`!
So it won't track any further changes.

Add `x:Bind ContactsViewSource.View, Mode=OneWay` to be sure it's tracking changes.

Also, I would rather add the Source of the CollectionViewSource in XAML like

```
 <CollectionViewSource x:Name="ContactsViewSource"
                       x:Key="src"
                       Source="{x:Bind FilterdValues, Mode=OneWay}"
                       IsSourceGrouped="True" />
```

And add that as a property and let the code inherit from `INotifyPropertyChanged` so that you can change that FilterValues in code instead of always reassigning the ContactsViewSource.Source in code...

Comment: _"note that x:Bind default behaviour is `OneTime`"_ - OMG! Thanks I did not realise this after recently moving to UWP.  Thank-you

Comment: @MickyD make sure you keep this in your hat. this is behavior for all element source binding.

Answer (score 0):

The solution you're implementing right now doesn't take advantage of the built-in animations that ListView has - resetting the source after each text change will cause a whole new list to appear in place each time.

Instead, you can directly go through the ListView's ItemsSource and remove/add back items after each text change. With this method, individual items will animate to disappear and appear.

[Here's](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/listview-filtering) a recently published article on Windows Dev Docs about filtering a collection in UWP.